# What is the name of script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Such scripts are often used at different tubes (video hostings). When the user mouse over the screenshot thumbnail, that screenshot replaces with next one, and so on. When the mouse out, the first image shows there. I need to get the name of such type of scripts, (like rollover, carousel, slideshow) to look in google for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Rollover" is the best fit for what I think you're describing. You use the `mouseover` / `mouseout` or `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` events (those latter are IE-specific, but jQuery provides them on all browsers and they're a bit easier to use sometimes) to receive notification you should change an image, then you swap out the image (by assigning to the `img` element's `src` property, by hiding one `img` element and showing another, by playing CSS games, etc. -- there are lots of ways).

So for example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ituzul)):

HTML:

```
<p data-img="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">Mousing over this paragraph shows my gravatar.</p>
<p data-img="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8b12d17e2b54660de108a0995e1b5c3f?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">Mousing over this one shows yours.</p>
<p>If you're not over either, we show Jon Skeet's.</p>
<img id="theImage" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6d8ebb117e8d83d74ea95fbdd0f87e13?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var img = $("#theImage"),
      defaultImg = img[0].src;
  $("p[data-img]")
    .mouseenter(function() {
      img[0].src = $(this).attr("data-img");
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      img[0].src = defaultImg;
    });
});
```

That's just a very, very basic example. It's also common to pre-load the images (which I haven't done above), either by just using other `img` elements that are off-page (say, `style="position: absolute; left: -10000px"`), or by loading them from script (by creating `img` elements and assigning their `src`). That way, when it's time to switch images, the browser already has the image in cache and it happens quite smoothly.

Comment: To expand on this, usually the rotation of images is handled by a function called `setInterval`, which is usually tied to the `mouseover` event, and `clearInterval`, which is tied to the `mouseout` event.

Comment: @Bryan: I wouldn't have said so, not in what the OP describes. In slideshows and such, sure.

Comment: The sequential images are usually fetched via AJAX as well, I believe, before cycling between them.

Comment: @TJ: Ahhh.. I immediately thought of the rotating screenshot effect that a lot of video sites use, based on his question.

Comment: @GregL: It's common to pre-fetch them, either with markup or with script, but not via Ajax specifically.